# counting hours and adding minutes in time in php

Tags: php

everyone i have a problem i can't count the hours in time....

this is my codes:

```
    $seconds =mktime (0,0,0);
$hours = (int)($seconds / (60 * 60));
```

can anyone help me determine what's my wrong?..

THANKS!

Comment: Depends on what you actually need to do: `mktime` returns the number of seconds passed since the Epoch Time (Jan 1 1970) so your code counts how many hours have passed since then.

Comment: what is overall objective anyways ? care to be more precise ?

Comment: ah!!!...thanks you!...how about when i use the time(); is it still thesame?...and also how can i add 1min. to the time?...

Comment: time() will return the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch.
To add 1 minute more, `$newTime = time() + 60`, note that this will be in seconds, if you want date/time format(hours:min:sec), do `date('H:i:s', $newTime)` OR to directly get hours use `date('H',$newTime)`. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php for more help on date and time functions respectively.

Comment: time() give you the passed time since Jan 1 1970 in seconds. Therefore adding a minute to time() is time() + 60 :)

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function which manipulates timestamp.

Examples:

```
<?php

$one_minute_later = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 minute'));
// Same as
$one_minute_later = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() + 60);

$one_hour_later = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 day'));
$one_day_later = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 day'));

$now = time(); // Current timestamp
```