# Calculate date interval in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, date, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subtracting dates in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090067/subtracting-dates-in-php)

I have two Unix timestamps, how can I calculate the total number of days between them?

Comment: You can use this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837474/counting-hours-and-adding-minutes-in-time-in-php/4837607#4837607

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$timestamp1 = x;
$timestamp2 = y;

$days_elapsed = floor(($timestamp2 - $timestamp1)/86400);

echo $days_elapsed;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Convert them to UNIX-timestamp](http://php.net/mktime) (if they arent already), then just

```
$diff = abs($timestamp1 - $timestamp2);
$days = (int) ($diff / 60 / 60 / 24);
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do the trick: 
      `$days = (strtotime($timestamp1)-strtotime($timestamp2))/(60*60*24);`

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick

```
$numDays = abs($timeOne - $timeTwo)/60/60/24;
```